# Why KeyListener does not receive the events when you add a JPanel with buttons?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I have the following Java swing application:

[image: KeyListener Test App]

It consists of:

- A JFrame (Window)
- A JPanel with AWT Buttons (Buttons)
- A red JPanel
- A green JPanel
- A class that implements KeyListener (KeyboardHandler)

If I do not include Buttons, KeyListener works, I press a key and I see the keycode in the output window. But as soon as I add the Buttons class, key events no longer are displayed in the output window.

Why?

The main function is as follows:

```java
package testkeyboard;

public class TestKeyboard {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Window w = new Window();
        w.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

The Window class is as follows:

```java
package testkeyboard;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    
    Buttons buttons;
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;
    
    public Window() {

        buttons = new Buttons();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
        
        this.setSize(640, 480);
        this.getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);   
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);   
        this.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);   
        
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyboardHandler());
    }
    

}
```

The class that implements KeyListener is as follows:

```java
package testkeyboard;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyboardHandler implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("KEYCODE: " + event.getKeyCode());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        //printEventInfo("Key Released", event);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        //printEventInfo("Key Typed", event);
    }

}
```

The class with the buttons is as follows:

```java
package testkeyboard;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Buttons extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
            
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    
    public Buttons() {
        
        button1 = new Button("B1");
        button2 = new Button("B2");
        button3 = new Button("B3");
        
        button1.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
        button2.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
        button3.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); 
        
        this.add(button1);
        this.add(button2);
        this.add(button3);
        
        this.setBackground(Color.blue);
        this.setForeground(Color.white);

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));                  
                
    }    
            
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source.equals(button1)) {
            System.out.println("BUTTON 1 CLICK");
        }
        else if (source.equals(button2)) {
            System.out.println("BUTTON 2 CLICK");
        }
        else if (source.equals(button3)) {
            System.out.println("BUTTON 3 CLICK");
        }        

    }
        
}
```

EDIT: The question has been marked as duplicated, the SO question pointed deals with a `KeyListener` in a `JPanel`, while this question deals with a `KeyListener` in a `JFrame`. It also lacks a complete example.

Therefore in case it might be useful for someone else I include the `Window` class code including how to use `KeyBindings` in this case:

```java
public class Window extends JFrame {
    
    Buttons buttons;
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;
    
    public Window() {

        buttons = new Buttons();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
        
        this.setSize(640, 480);
        this.getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);   
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);   
        this.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);   
        
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyboardHandler());
        
        InputMap iMap = ((JComponent)(this.getContentPane())).getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap aMap = ((JComponent)(this.getContentPane())).getActionMap();
        
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "doSomething");
        aMap.put("doSomething", doSomething);
    };
        
    Action doSomething = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("actionPerformed!");
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: KeyListener will only work if the listened to component has focus. If focus is lost, then the listener no longer functions. Use Key Bindings to get around this restriction

Comment: So as soon as I add the JPanel with the buttons, the focus is on the buttons and therefore I stop receiving the events, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: Again, I would use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (check the link for the tutorial) in place of a KeyListener in 99% of situations. I also would avoid using AWT components, such as `java.awt.Button`, in a Swing application but instead would use the Swing equivalent, `javax.swing.JButton`.

Comment: I tried Key Bindings and they work. I had to do use  `(JComponent)getContentPane()` to get the input map and the action map because I was applying the key bindings to the `JFrame` (not sure if it is mandatory to apply them to a JPanel). The reason for using an AWT button is that in FreeBSD/MWM the button can be displayed as a flat non-decorated button, which is what I want in this particular case. I think the same effect with Swing buttons is difficult to get.

Comment: *the button can be displayed as a flat non-decorated button, which is what I want in this particular case.* - with a Swing JButton you use `setBorder(null)`

Comment: Thanks, after @HovercraftFullOfEels comment I found in a SO question that I could use `setBorder` as you mention. Also `setMargins(new Innsets(0,0,0,0))` is needed to get something closer to AWT buttons.